# Laravel user role access content in view

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware

Have more than 150 views which has table content with the columns edit,view and add. I want to restrict view according to user role. For ex. if the admin login, he can able to see all the options, if other he can only add not delete and edit. How can we achieve this? One way is calling different views for diff roles but this is not redudant and even there is more than 150 views.

Comment: You can use middleware for that. Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication) and specifically the "Protecting Routes" section

Comment: Authentication has done and even showing tabs according to role but my requirement is restrict columns in table for diffferent role

Comment: Have a little study on `Laravel Authorization` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Answer (score 1):

### Conditional rendering in Blade

You can check the user permission in your views and then decide what the user should be able to see and what not.

```
@if(Auth::user()->admin) 
    <input name="website_logo_url" type="text" />
@endif
```

### Use middleware

You can deny the access to certain views by using a middleware.

- Create the middleware with artisan: `php artisan make:middlware MiddlewareName`
- Define your middleware behavior by following Laravel Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Comment: Ya this is one of the idea but have more than 150 views and even around 10 roles . This soln will could be more if else condition and need to add in all pages. Any other soln

Comment: Do you need to hide entire views or just parts of views? If you need to hide some URL's to make them unavailable to people not having permission, you can do it by using middlewares, if you need to hide parts of views it will take you some time, you will need to edit those views and add them the behaviour you need..


PS: It's a really bad practice, but you can generate the views and capture the HTML buffer before it reaches the user with ob_start, ob_end_flush etc. PHP functions. Then you can remove some HTML, but I repeat: it's very bad to do this in Laravel because you already have Blade!

Answer (score 0):

When u have a table with roles in your database you can do something like this in your web.php file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'], function() {

....

});
```

Then you make a middleware called "AdminMiddleware" or something like that.

Every route you set inside that middleware group is restricted to what you put inside the middleware file. Take a look at this middleware file:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $allowed_role_ids = [2];

    if (!in_array($request->user()->role_id, $allowed_role_ids))
    {
        return redirect('/')->with('flash', 'U heeft hier geen toegang voor');
    } elseif(Auth::guest()) {

        return redirect('/')->with('flash', 'U bent een gast, U heeft hier geen toegang voor');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

If the user's request role ID is not the allowed role_ID it is not allowed to access that route. If it is, it will redirect to the desired route. I hope this fixes your issue.